# $p$ multi-variate polynomial over Finite Field for prime $p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Does there exist a $23$ $(p = 23)$ variate (variable) polynomial $P(x, x_1, x_2..., x_{22})$ where every integer $n$ has a solution in $P(x, x_1, x_2..., x_{22})$ if and only if all divisors of $n$ are congruent to $0$ or $1$ $\pmod 23$.

For $p = 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19$ this is proven to be the case because the cyclotomic fields are PID.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I apologize if this comes off as rude but seriously, what are you talking about? More concretely, what do you mean by integers in a polynomial?

Comment: "In which every integer $n$ ..." seems very incomplete.